# Android Studio - XML Editor suggestions not working and fewer properties

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm using

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 8, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3

and this is I see the attributes panel

[image]

and

[image]

I have delete the .idea folder, the .iml files and click "invalidate cache and restart"

Any other solutions?